# Getting error while using TeamCity command line tool. What is missing?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to use TeamCity command line tool but receiving an error? What is missing?

The command executed:
java -jar tcc.jar info --host http://tc

The output:

```
[Connecting to "http://tc" TeamCity Server] started
[Connecting to "http://tc" TeamCity Server] done
[Logging in] started
[Logging in] done
[ ] info: error
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No enum constant jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor.CheckoutType.AUTO : No enum constant jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor.CheckoutType.AUTO
---- Debugging information ----
message : No enum constant jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor.CheckoutType.AUTO
cause-exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
cause-message : No enum constant jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor.CheckoutType.AUTO
class : jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor$CheckoutType
required-type : jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeDescriptor$CheckoutType
converter-type : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.enums.EnumConverter
path : /Project/configs/Configuration/checkoutType
line number : 1
class[1] : jetbrains.buildServer.BuildTypeData
converter-type[1] : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2] : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type[2] : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
class[3] : jetbrains.buildServer.ProjectData
version : null
-------------------------------
```

Comment: maybe different versions of teamcity and client?

Comment: I downloaded tcc.jar from the teamcity server, so it should be the same version... I just thought maybe the version on server is old... Will check. Thanks!